# How many integer multiples of $1001$ can be expressed in the form $(10^i) - (10^j)$ where $i$ and $j$ are integers with $0 ≤ i < j ≤ 99$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Hi I have been working on this problem and I don't understand my textbook's solution to this problem.

Here is my textbook's solution to the problem:

We have 1001 = 7*11*13 and the condition of the problem says 7*11*13*k = 10^j - 10^i = (10^i)(10^(j-I) - 1). This implies 10^j-i = 1 (mod 1001) (and also (mod 7)). Since phi(7) = 6, by Euler's totient theorem, j-I = 0 (mod 6). If j-I = 6 we have 94 possibilities for j-I: 6-0, 7-1, ..., 99-93. If j-I = 12 we have 94-6 = 88 possibilities for j-I: 12-0, 13-1, ... , 99-87. The last case is j-I = 96 where we have 4 possibilities: 96-0, 97-1, 98-2, and 99-3. In total we have 94+88+82+...+10+4 = 16 * (98/2) = 784 possibilities.

I don't get how (10^i)(10^(j-I) - 1) implies 10^(j-I) = 1 (mod 1001) and (mod 7), or why my textbook used the totient function on 7, instead of 1001. I also don't quite understand their method for finding the different possibilities for j-I.

Comment: $10^j - 10^i = 0 \mod 1001$ so $(10^{j-i} - 1)10^i = 0 \mod 1001$.  gcd(10^i, 1001 = 10^3 + 1) = 1.  So $10^{j-i} - 1 = 0 \mod 1001$ so $10^{j-i} = 1 \mod 1001$.

Comment: tortient (7) is smaller than tortient(1001).  So getting j-1 = 0 mod 6 and j-1 = 0 mod tor(1001) = 0 mod  720 but 0 mod 720 will be too hard and too many cases to test.

Comment: If 0 <= i < j <= 99 means 1 <= j-i <= 99.  j-i = 0 mod 6 so we have j-i = 6; 12;18;.....; 96.  If j-i = 6 then i = j -6.  so we have 0 <= i <= 99-6=93.  That's 94 possibilities.  If j-i = 12 then i = j-12.  so 0 <=i <= 99-12= 87.  That's 88 possibilities.  If j-i = 6k then i = j - 6k so 0<=i < = 99 - 6k.  That 99 - 6k +1 = 100 - 6k possibilities.  Add them up (100- 6) + (100 - 12) +....+(100 - 6k) + .....(100 - 96) = (100+100+.....) - 6(1+2 +.... + 16) = 16(100) - 6(1+2+ .... + 16).

Comment: Actually, the real question you should be asking is that although 10^(j-i) = 1 mod 7 is nescessary, why does the the text assume it is sufficient.  In other words 1001|10^j - 10^k $\implies$ 10^{j - i} = 1 mod 7 but it doesn't follow that $10^{j-i} = 1 \mod 7 \implies 1001|10^j - 10^k$.  As it turns out it because 999999 = 999*1001 but in general it doesn't: ex  1001|10^j - 10^i => 10^(j-i) = 1 mod 11 => j-i = 0 mod 10 but 10^10 - 1 = 9999999999 is not divisible by 11.

Answer (score 1):

You have $7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot k$ is a multiple of $1001$.  You know $10^I$ is not a multiple of $1001$, so the other factor $10^{j-I}-1$ must be a multiple of $1001$ and hence of all its factors.   The rest of the proof is incorrect but results in the correct answer.  Euler's totient theorem says that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for $a$ coprime to $n$.  As $7$ is prime, $\phi(7)=6$, so if $j-I$ is a multiple of $6, 10^{j-I}\equiv 1 \pmod 7$  What they say is $10^{j-I}\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ proves that $j-I$ must be a multiple of $6$.  The book is reading the implication in the wrong direction.  We can see the problem by looking at another factor of $1001,$ which is $11$.  The book argument would also claim that we must have $j-I$ a multiple of $10$, but in fact working $\bmod 11$ only tells us that $j-I$ is even, which we knew already.  We know that $10^6 \equiv 3^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ but nothing in the argument shows that no lower power of $10$ is also $\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.  That is what happens for $11$ and $13$, so all cases where $6|(j-I)$ result in $10^j-10^I$ being a multiple of $1001$

Comment: In short $1001|10^k - 10^i \implies k - i \equiv 0 \mod 6$ but the text failed to show $k - i \equiv 0 \mod 6 \implies 1001|10^k - 10^i$.  As it turnns out, it does, but not for any reason the text demonstrated.

Comment: $10^6 - 1 = 999999 = 999*1001$ so $10^j - 10^{j - 6k} = (10^{6k} - 1)*10^{j-6k}$.  $10^{6k} -1 =(10^3 + 1)(10^{6k -3} - 10^{6k - 6} + .... - 10^6 + 1)$.  But that isn't anything the text explains.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't get how $(10^i)(10^{(j-I)} - 1)$ implies $10^{(j-I)} = 1 (\mod 1001)$

$1001k = 10^j - 10^i \iff 10^j - 10^i \equiv 0 \mod 1001$

So $10^{i}(10^{j-i}-1) \equiv 0 \mod 1001$.

$\gcd(10^i, 1001) = \gcd(2^i*5^i, 7*11*13) = 1$.

So $10^{i}(10^{j-i}-1) \equiv 0 \mod 1001 \iff 10^{j-i} - 1 \equiv 1001 \iff 10^{j-i} \equiv 1 \mod 1001$

so $10^{j-1} - 1001k = 1$ so $10^{j-i} - 7(11*13*k) = 1$

so $10^{j-i} \equiv 1 \mod 7$.

" and (mod 7), or why my textbook used the totient function on 7, instead of 1001"$

Because it's easier.  $\phi(7) =6$ and $\phi(1001) = 720$.  $6$ is an easier number to work with

" I also don't quite understand their method for finding the different possibilities for j-I. "

By Fermat's Little Theorem $10^{\phi(7) = 6} \equiv 1 \mod 7$.  So if $10^{j-1} = 1 \mod 7$ then $j - i$ must be a multiple of $6$ (i.e. $j-i \equiv 0 \mod 6$).

As $0 \le i < j \le 99$ then $1 \le j-i \le 99$.  So $j-1 = 6;12;18;24;....;96$.

If $j-i = 6$ then $i = j - 6$ as $1 \le j \le 99$ then $0 = 6-6 \le i \le 99 -6 = 93$.  That is 94 = 100 - 6 possibilities.

If $j-i = 12 = 6*2$ then $i = j - 12$ and $0 \le i \le 99 -12 = 87$.  That is $88 = 100 - 12 = 100 - 2*6$ possibilities.

If $j-i = 6*k$ then $i = j - 6k$ and $0 \le i \le 99 - 6k$. That is $99 - 6k + 1 = 100 - 6k$ possibilities.

Add these possibilities up:  (100 - 6) + (100 - 12) + ...... + (100 - 96)

That is $\sum_{k=1}^16 (100 - 6k) = \sum_{k=1}^16 100 - \sum_{k=1}^16 6k = 16*100 -6 \sum_{k=1}^16 k = 1600 - 6*\frac{16*(16+1)}2$.

=====

Actually though.  I think your text is wrong.

Although $1001|10^j - 10^i \implies 10^{j-i} \equiv 1 \mod 7$  (and also $1 \mod 11$ and $1 \mod 13$).

$ \implies j - i \equiv 0 \mod 6$ (and also $0 \mod 10$ and $0 \mod 12$).

It doesn't follow that $j-i \equiv 0 \mod 6 \implies 1001|10^j - 10^i$ (nor do $0 \mod 10$ or $0 \mod 12$ imply $1001|10^j - 10^i$).

As it turns out $j - i \equiv 0 \mod 6$ does actually imply $10^{j-1} - 1 = 999...9$ a multiple of six nines. = $999*1001*(1000001000001.......000001)$.

But that was a coincidence that 1001 = $10^3 + 1$ and $3|6$.

It wouldn't follow $j-i \equiv 0 \mod 10$ implies $1001|10^j - 10^i$ as $10^{10} -1 = 9999999999 = 9*11*101010101= 9*11*101* 10001= 9*11*101*73*137$ .

So the proof is invalid.

====

Can anyone double check my reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the second answer but you book just gives the wrong reason.

Instead here's the "pretty picture" way:

$10^j - 10^i = 100000..... - 1000....  = 99999999.....90000.....$

where there are $j-i$ 9's and $i$ zeros.  This is divisble by $1001$ only if $999...9 = 10^{j-i} -1$ is.

So take some pencil and paper and do the problem $99999.... \div 1001$.  If you do long division (try it) you get:  $999000999000.....$ and this only divides evenly if and only if $j - i$ is a multiple of $6$.

But that's a very informal proof.

More formally we can do what your text does.  $10^j - 10^i = (10^{j-i} - 1)10^i$.  As $\gcd(10^i, 1001) = 1$, $1001|10^j - 10^i \iff 1001|10^{j-i}-1$.

Your text shows that $1001|10^{j-i} - 1 \implies 10^{j-i} \equiv 1 \mod (7|11|13)$ But that's not enough to go the other way.  The text is dead wrong about that.

But let $k = j-i$.  If $6|k$ so $k = 6n$ then we have $10^{6n} - 1 = (10^3+1)(10^{6k -3} - 10^{6k - 6}+....+10^9 - 10^6 + 10^3 - 1)= (1001)*\sum_{l=0}^{2k-1}(-1)^{l+1}10^{3k}$.

So $10^3 +1|10^{6n} -1$.

But are these the *only* answers?

Well, yes.  If $6 \not \mid k$ then by Fermat's Little theoem if $k \equiv l \mod 6; l \ne 0$ then $10^k \equiv 10^l \not \equiv 1 \mod 7$.  So $10^k \not \equiv 1 \mod 1001$ and $1001 \not \mid 10^k - 1$ and $1001 \not \mid 10^j - 10^i$.

Thus the text did get the right answer for the wrong reasons.